# How to create a new file containing an existing file's content in vim

Tags: vim

I want to create a file with a block of code in it and then, when I open a new file, this block is already in the file without having to copy paste every time. Something like:

```
:e newfile.cpp/template.cpp
```

where I now have a new file named newfile.cpp and it has the contents of template.cpp in it; template.cpp will just sit in my directory and wont be changed unless I open it specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `|`(bar) to concate two commands:

```
:e newfile.cpp | r template.cpp
```

- create a new file
- read the template

Answer (score 3):

One generic possibility is simply to use this command:

```
:r template.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave your template opened and use:

```
:saveas newfile.cpp
```

Or, use one snippets plugin like [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540) or [XPTemplate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2611) to implement a similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If rely on templates a lot, you probably need something more advanced. There are several such plugins on vim.org; one is [tSkeleton](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1160).